# EJB JPA based Application is throwing NPE after exactly 1 hour and 10 minutes

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, oracle-adf

After monitoring ADF's behavior using EJB JPA,we noticed that every 1 hour and 10 minutes exactly the Iterator refreshes, which is causing a null pointer exception in getcurrentrow (DCIteratorBinding) function . but how can we avoid refreshing the iterator(ps:we tried the session timeout).

if i use this function from sessionbean it will work fine with a table and a form in my JSFF view

```
    /** <code>select o from Person o</code> */
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public List<Person> getPersonFindAll() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll", 
    Person.class).getResultList();
    }    /** <code>select o from Person o</code> */
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public List<Person> getPersonFindAll() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll", 
    Person.class).getResultList();
    }
```

but if i use this function without a table in my JSFF view it will call it again after 1 hour and 10 minutes causing loss in modified and unsaved work that the user made

```
            public Person getPersonById() {
                Person person = new Person();
                ADFContext adfCtx = ADFContext.getCurrent();
                Map pageFlowScope = adfCtx.getPageFlowScope();
                Object idObj = pageFlowScope.get("id");
                System.out.println(" getPersonById !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! id = "+idObj);
                String id  = (String) idObj;
                    person = em.find(Person.class, id);
                return person;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This look like a classic issue of misconfigured Application Module.

**Cause** : Your application module is timing out and releasing it's transaction before the official adfc-config timeout value.

**To Fix** : Go to the application module containing this VO > Configuration > Edit the default > **Modify Idle Instance Timeout** to be the same as your adf session timeout (Take time to validate the other configuration aswell)

Comment: hello cedric where can i find it ?

Comment: Your Application Module ? it look like a briefcase like this : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/web.111240/e16182/intro_tour.htm#ADFFD22307

Comment: this is a Business Module based application, i am using EJB/JPA based application but it should have a similar solution.